# Running an environment with docker-compose

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file like so:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: darajava/audio-diary
    ports:
      - 80:3001
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - "/app/node_modules"
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: "soliloquy_express"

  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=soliloquy
      - MYSQL_USER=soliloquy
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ../db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: "soliloquy_db"
```

I'm planning to add an nginx service here too.

I use

```
docker-compose build
```

and

```
docker-compose push
```

to push to Docker Hub, which I can pull from (from my EC2 instance) using:

```
docker pull darajava/audio-diary:latest
```

However, when I run that image, it only runs the `app` service (I think).

using

```
docker-compose pull darajava/audio-diary:latest
```

does not work and leads to an error regarding a missing `docker-compose.yml` file.

So I have 2 questions:

Is there a way I can pull a whole `docker-compose` config, with `app`, `db`, and other services and pull and run it on my EC2 instance just by pulling from Docker Hub? or do I have the wrong use case for Docker Compose?

Comment: Docker Hub only stores images. If you want to have your docker-compose.yml file available, you need to store it somewhere else, like in a Github repo.

Comment: (Make sure you delete the `volumes:` block for the `app` service: it requires you to have a local copy of your application source code in addition to the built Docker image, and it overrides the library tree with unmanaged content in a named volume.)

Comment: @HansKilian won't that make my CI/CD far more complex? Now if I want to implement CI/CD, I would need to include github access tokens and pull from the repo each time etc, etc. Isn't that a nightmare? Seems barbaric to me.

Comment: Nightmare? Barbaric? That's literally how every CI/CD platform works. And any decent CI/CD platform has facilities for integrating with a Git repository securely, and automatically pulling the latest code from the repository as a step in the build process.